# Json file content extract and copy to excel/text

Tags: python, json, shell

I have below JSON file from which I want to extract only

```
("workers": {"usersRunning": 1, "usersWaiting": 0, "total": 8, "jobsWaiting": 0, "inUse": 4})
```

part, and then put it into csv file or text file (tab deliminated). I am new to python so any help will be apprciated..

```
{
    "workers": {
        "usersRunning": 1,
        "usersWaiting": 0,
        "total": 8,
        "jobsWaiting": 0,
        "inUse": 4
    },
    "users": {
        "activeUsers": 1,
        "activity": [{
            "maxWorkers": 4,
            "inProgress": 4,
            "displayName": "abc",
            "waiting": 0
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are new to Python you should work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: If the parsed JSON is in `data`, use `json['workers']` to get that part.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using pandas. It has methods to read the json and you can use dataframe filtering to find the data you need.

Examples here: https://www.listendata.com/2019/07/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe.html

Comment: Pandas is a bit overboard for this just use `data['workers']`

Comment: Can pandas do a lot more? Yes, sure. Does that mean you  can't use it for simple stuff? No. And introducing him to a powerful library is a benefit of its own.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use pandas and convert to excel
The following is sample that will help you to get your answer

```
json_ = {"workers": {"usersRunning": 1, "usersWaiting": 0, "total": 8, "jobsWaiting": 0, "inUse": 4}, "users": {"activeUsers": 1, "activity": [{"maxWorkers": 4, "inProgress": 4, "displayName": "abc", "waiting": 0}]}}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data= json_['workers'], index=[0])
df.to_excel('json_.xlsx')
```